# WPF:Difference between TabControl.ItemTemplate and TabItem.ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm confused on this for a long time,these both seem to affect the tabitems' presentation in the tabcontrol.
Is it designed for best control of the presentation of the tabcontrol?
Or if there is something I dont't understand.

Comment: I believe that does the same things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` Property is used to define what each item in the data bound collection should look like... from the [`ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> Gets or sets the DataTemplate used to display each item.

As you can see, it is of type `DataTemplate`, which is customary for a template that displays data... its `DataContext` will automatically be set to an item from the collection and so controls declared in that `DataTemplate` will automatically have access to the items properties. Please see the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further help with this.

Similarly, from MSDN, the [`ContentControl.ContentTemplate` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets the data template used to display the content of the `ContentControl`.

Again, its `DataContext` will automatically be set to the object that is set as the `Content` property. Please note that the `ContentControl` only has a `ContentTemplate` Property and no `ItemTemplate` Property, which is used for collection items... from the Data Templating Overview page on MSDN:

> Because myTaskTemplate is a resource, you can now use it on other controls that have a property that takes a DataTemplate type. As shown above, for ItemsControl objects, such as the ListBox, it is the ItemTemplate property. For ContentControl objects, it is the ContentTemplate property.

---

UPDATE >>>

To clarify this situation further, think of this simple rule:

> Use the `ContentTemplate` property to define how an object that is set as the `Content` property of a `ContentControl` should look.
>
> Use the `ItemTemplate` property to define how the *items* of a collection control should look.

That the difference at its simplest. However, I'd like to point out that as these properties are both of type `DataTemplate`, their values *are* interchangeable.

For example, let's say that you have a `Person` class and you display a collection of `Person` objects in a `ListBox`. You can declare a `DataTemplate` to set as the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property to define how each `Person` in the collection should look. However, if you just wanted to display a single `Person`, then you could use a `ContentControl` with the `Content` set to an instance of the `Person` class, and still use the *same* `DataTemplate`, but set as the `ContentTemplate` instead:

Multiple objects:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}" ... />
```

...

Single object:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Person}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template}" ... />
```

Comment: Awesome explaination.Thanks a lot,Sheridan.

Answer (score 42):

There's some very long answers here for what is actually a very simple question. To avoid confusion:

`ItemTemplate` is the template used to format each item in the `ItemsSource` to create the headers (the controls that appear in the tab bar) and `ContentTemplate` is the template used to format each item in the `ItemsSource` to create the content of the tabs (the controls that appear when you click on the header).

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Setting the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` you specify a template to use for all `TabItems` in the `Items` collection of the `TabControl`, unless you override the `TabItem.ContentTemplate` for a specific `TabItem`.</strike>

So, while they do the same, `TabControl.ItemTemplate` is a more generic template for all the `TabItems` in the `TabControl` and `TabItem.ContentTemplate` is specific for the `TabItem` it is used in.

The above is not quite true, as `TabControl` has an `ItemTemplate` property and a `ContentTemplate` property, to make it more confusing.

`ItemTemplate` is used as template for the header (the tab thingy) of all `TabItems` added through databinding on the `ItemsSource` or through Xaml without making the the added item a `TabItem`:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

This will create a `TabControl` with red text in the header/tab and blue text for content.

Now, if we do the following:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

    <TabItem Header="One" Content="One"/>
    <TabItem Header="Two" Content="Two"/>
    <TabItem Header="Three" Content="Three"/>
</TabControl>
```

We'll have a `TabControl` with three tabs, and the header text is black, content is still blue. And a DataError informing us that the `ItemTemplate` and `ItemTemplateSelector` properties are ignored for items already of the `ItemsControl's` container type, in this case `TabItem`. In this case, we need to specify `TabItem.HeaderTemplate` to change the appearance of the header.

So `TabControl.ItemTemplate` and `TabItem.ContentTemplate` don't do the same, but my previous explanation still holds for `TabControl.ContentTemplate` and `TabItem.ContentTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks,your explaination is useful

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite right. Just checked and found out that `TabControl` has an `ItemTemplate` property and a `ContentTemplate` property. Will update my answer to reflect that in a moment.

Comment: So conclusion is : the tabControl(or ListBox) is itemsControl which means its property like itemTemplate is only responsible for its own item form its itemssource.And it won't work on the object added in other ways. Am I right?