# wpf help binding data to controls in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, tabcontrol

So I have a TabControl with two TabItems, each TabItem has the same controls on it (8 TextBlocks) and will display data under the same bindings as their counterparts on the other TabItem.
The xaml and cs code that I have is below, but when I try execute it I get this error.

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

### XAML for TabItem Structure

```
<TabControl Name="tbcIndividualStats" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="652" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1338" ItemsSouce="{Binding tabcontrolitems}">
  <!--Template for all tabs (idea is to have them dynamically created eventually)-->
  <!--Content template-->
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <!--Border just holds the stuff-->
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF53535B" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="452" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="520" Margin="10,135,0,0">
          <StackPanel Margin="0,0,-1,0">
            <TextBlock Name="txtVenue" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Venue}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTopSpeed" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TopSpeed}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtDistRun" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DistRun}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeLow" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeLow}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeMed" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeMed}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeHigh" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeHigh}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeSprint" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeSprint}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtSprintDist" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding SprintDist}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

  <!--Item Template-->
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <!--Border just holds the stuff-->
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF53535B" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="452" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="520" Margin="10,135,0,0">
          <StackPanel Margin="0,0,-1,0">
            <TextBlock Name="txtVenue" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Venue}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTopSpeed" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TopSpeed}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtDistRun" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DistRun}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeLow" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeLow}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeMed" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeMed}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeHigh" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeHigh}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeSprint" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeSprint}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtSprintDist" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding SprintDist}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <TabItem Header="PlayerName" Background="Transparent" />
  <TabItem Header="PlayerName2" Background="Transparent" />
</TabControl>
```

### C# for Binding Data

```
public class TabItemContent
{
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string TopSpeed { get; set; }
    public string DistRun { get; set; }
    public string TimeLow { get; set; }
    public string TimeMed { get; set; }
    public string TimeHigh { get; set; }
    public string TimeSprint { get; set; }
    public string DistSprint { get; set; }
}

public void foo()
{
//All one line of code
//FileLoadData is a List of another class where all my data is stored
var tabitemcontents = new List<TabItemContent> { new TabItemContent { Venue = FileLoadData[0].Venue, TopSpeed = FileLoadData[0].TopSpeed.ToString(), DistRun = FileLoadData[0].TotalDistance.ToString(), TimeLow = FileLoadData[0].TimeLow.ToString(),
        TimeMed = FileLoadData[0].TimeMed.ToString(), TimeHigh = FileLoadData[0].TimeHigh.ToString(), TimeSprint = FileLoadData[0].TimeSprint.ToString(), DistSprint = "null"},
        new TabItemContent { Venue = FileLoadData[1].Venue, TopSpeed = FileLoadData[1].TopSpeed.ToString(), DistRun = FileLoadData[1].TotalDistance.ToString(), TimeLow = FileLoadData[1].TimeLow.ToString(),
        TimeMed = FileLoadData[1].TimeMed.ToString(), TimeHigh = FileLoadData[1].TimeHigh.ToString(), TimeSprint = FileLoadData[1].TimeSprint.ToString(), DistSprint = "null"}};

//Error here, supposed to add to the TabItems
tbcIndividualStats.ItemsSource = tabitemcontents;
}
```

I've been looking for a solution for ages and I can't get one to work. I just need to bind that data from FileLoadData[0] and FileLoadData[1] to the two TabItems respectivly.

Comment: You cannot set both itemsource and add tabitem in xaml to the tabcontrol. Just set Itemsource

Comment: Remove the <TabItem> elements from the XAML. You can't both add items in the XAML and use an ItemsSource.

Comment: Are ContentTemplate and ItemTemplate the same?

Comment: @Babbillumpa yep, tbh wasnt sure of the difference, all the examples i've seen have them looking almost identical, could you explain the difference? (I'm new at wpf)

Comment: @MattWilson check the answer, i tried to give you a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adopt a different strategy:

Add to your model, the name that you want to show in the **Header** of the Tabitem:

```
public class TabItemContent
{
    public string PlayerName {get; set;}  // New Property for the Tabitem Header
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string TopSpeed { get; set; }
    public string DistRun { get; set; }
    public string TimeLow { get; set; }
    public string TimeMed { get; set; }
    public string TimeHigh { get; set; }
    public string TimeSprint { get; set; }
    public string DistSprint { get; set; }
}
```

Then i'd change the Xaml considering this new attribute:

```
<TabControl Name="tbcIndividualStats" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="652" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1338">
  <!--Template for all tabs (idea is to have them dynamically created eventually)-->
  <!--Content template-->
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <!--Border just holds the stuff-->
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF53535B" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="452" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="520" Margin="10,135,0,0">
          <StackPanel Margin="0,0,-1,0">
            <TextBlock Name="txtVenue" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Venue}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTopSpeed" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TopSpeed}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtDistRun" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DistRun}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeLow" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeLow}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeMed" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeMed}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeHigh" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeHigh}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtTimeSprint" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimeSprint}" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtSprintDist" Margin="10,7" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding SprintDist}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

  <!--Item Template-->
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border>
            <Textblock = Text="{Binding PlayerName}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**EDIT**: the item template is the template for the tabitem button and content template is for its content. Some references here: [TabItem.ItemTemplate vs TabItem.ContentTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265266/wpfdifference-between-tabcontrol-itemtemplate-and-tabitem-contenttemplate)

I've also removed the two TabItem defined inside TabControl.

Remember also to set the ItemsSource -> if you set it in code-behind, **remove** this line: `ItemsSouce="{Binding tabcontrolitems}"`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! Marked as answer.

Comment: And also while i've still got you here, would you be able to give a breif explanation of the difference between ItemTemplate and ContentTemplate?

Comment: @MattWilson I edited the answer with a little reference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these `<TabItem>` elements from the XAML:

```
<TabItem Header="PlayerName" Background="Transparent" />
<TabItem Header="PlayerName2" Background="Transparent" />
```

You can't both add individual items to the `TabControl` *and* use an `ItemsSource`. It's one way or the other.

Comment: ah thanks for that, it's stopped the error, but the problem is it doesn't seem to display the data in the TextBlocks, I looked at the visual tree and all the objects are there, but there was no text property set for any of the labels (all the data is correctly in the List beforehand though). And now that i've removed the two TabItems, how do I add them back exactly so I can have the headers to switch between?

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in the comments field. Once your *original* issue has been solved, you should ask another question if you have another issue.